# Why was Edward Norton replaced by Mark Ruffalo in "The Avengers"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, casting, the-avengers

In the movie [The Incredible Hulk](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800080/), there was a scene with Tony Stark having a conversation with Bruce Banner who was played by Edward Norton. So why didn't Joss Whedon choose him in his movie [The Avengers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/)?